# In C++ is there any way to apply a function 'simultaneously' to all the elements of a vector ?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I have a vector of length 6, with elements either 1 or zero. I want to apply 'XOR' on 2 elements on both sides of every ith element. e.g. for i = 1, I'll apply xor on 0th and 2nd element. the ith element is then replaced by this xor output. I want to apply xor for all such 'i's simultaneously on the original vector. Is there any way I can achieve this without using another vector?

Comment: Strange requiement, just use another vector.

Answer (score 2):

When you say "simultaneously", you mean that one XOR operation should not use the intermediate data from the previous XOR operation but the data from the original vector, right? In that case, since each step obliterates information (the previous state of element `i` is overwritten with the result), you can not do that without at least some intermediate storage. However, you only obliterate one bit of information and that information is only required in the next step, so you don't need a complete additional vector.

Comment: Yes, you got it right. I understand the intermediate storage would be needed but of course having that storage of size 'int' is efficient than having a full vector of 6 integers (in this problem).

Answer (score 1):

use a temporary variable to store previous item:

```
bool prev = vec[0];
for(int i = 1; i < vec.size() - 1; i++){
    bool result = vec[i + 1] ^ prev;
    prev = vec[i];
    vec[i] = result;
}
```

Comment: That nailed it, except for two things: The size is 6, so I'd `assert(vec.size() == 6)`. If you want to make this more generic for other sizes, you'd at least have to make sure the vector isn't empty before reading its first element. Anyhow, while this code looks good, I tend not to do other people's homework here on SO. ;)

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt You are right, but I thing seeing an example code can make good understanding of concept

Comment: Thanks Nima! That looks pretty simple now. I should have scratched my head a bit more.